# TYPO3: Add special menu CE and add class="active"

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

In [TYPO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPO3) one can insert a special menu as a content element, you can select about eight different ways to collect the menu.

In the menu I selected there is no class assigned if the menu item is active, and I need to highlight it with CSS. And I'd like to know how to add a custom menu.

Note: Once I did apply the solution supplied in my own answer I realized that the main difficulty was (and generally is in TYPO3) the caching, be aware to refresh frequently otherwise you'll never be sure what is correct code and what isn't...

Comment: you need to go to meta and the SO docs and see what deleting questions that are down voted does, especially ones with answers.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks, as a relative newcomer it did not suspect these rules, I'll try to enrich my question to earn my right to comment back ...

Comment: I keep receiving down-votes but I don't get it ... could somebody please inform me what seems wrong about this Q

Comment: The question is good. I was looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @johndoe33 thx... this question suffered the 'meta-effect' because I dared to put into discussion if downvoting should be a privilege for someone with reputation in the specific subject, in this case TYPO3, for which its easy to underestimate the effort to do some basic stuff...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336380/should-downvoting-be-enabled-by-competence-on-spec-tags-rather-than-reputation-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer:

---

1. Copy the original fluid template (menu of subpages of selected pages in my case):

   ```
   typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu/Type-1.html
   ```

   **TYPO3 v8**: different path and different names

   ```
   typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/xxx.html
   ```

   To (coherently to the directory you'll declare in point 4)

   ```
   EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu/Type-1.html
   ```
2. Add a variable that gives the current page id in your setup (libs.ts, probably this can be done easier and this value could be present already for use in point 3, but I wouldn't know how to code that).

   ```
   lib.pageId = TEXT
   lib.pageId.data = page:uid
   ```
3. Edit the template (I just give the applicable condition here)

   ```
   <f:if condition="{page.uid} == {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.pageId')}">
       ...
   </f:if>
   ```
4. Include the new fluid template (I overwrite the original one, keeping the original name)

   **TYPO3 v8**: use `lib.contentElement` instead of `lib.fluidContent`

   ```
   lib.fluidContent.partialRootPaths.1920 = EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu/
   ```

   Or as I did, include it in your page-setup

   ```
   page = PAGE
   page {
       # Page Main template
       10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
       10 {
           partialRootPaths = EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu/
       }
   }
   ```
5. If you'd like to add it as an option to the list you re-number the file (like Type-9.html) and add it to the menu in Page TSConfig:

   **TYPO3 v8**: i did not find a way to add a menu in v8, the config given here does not work ...

   ```
   TCEFORM.tt_content.menu_type {
      types {
         menu{
            addItems {
               9 = menu of subpages of selected pages active highlighted
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: In TYPO3 8.7 the location of templates of Menu content elements. They are in `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/`. e.g. `typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/MenuSubpages.html`

Answer (score 1):

To mark a link as active you need to activate the `ACT = 1`.

```
## MAIN Navigation [Begin]

    lib.Menu = HMENU
    lib.Menu {
        ## FIRST LEVEL ##
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            wrap = <ul>|</ul>
            expAll = 1
            noBlur = 1

            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

            ACT = 1
            ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    }

## MAIN Navigation [End]
```

Comment: thank you elvis ... indeed but where do I find the typoscript that generates the special menu, or how do I call it to overwrite !!

Comment: You can start by checking template module configurations.There should be the setup about it.

Comment: I'm talking about the special menus you insert as a content element ... am I misunderstanding something -> new content element -> second tab -> special menus, its not part of templates ...

Comment: https://pixelant.gitbooks.io/doc/content/custom_special_menu_templates.html - this gets me there, now I just have to find out how to fetch the current page UID for a condition in fluid