# TYPO3 Custom Menu Element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I am trying to create a custom menu element by using this in the Page TSConfig:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    menu_type.addItems.101 = My Menu
}
```

And this in Setup:

```
temp.my_menu = HMENU
temp.my_menu {
  special = list
  special.value.field = pages 
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }
}
tt_content.menu.20.101 < temp.my_menu
```

But I get 'Oops, an error occurred!' where the menu should be.
It will render fine if I remove the Fluid includes in the template but then all the other content elements give errors.

Is there any way to have a typoscript menu element at the same time as fluid styled content?

Or if I really have to, how do I add a custom fluid menu template?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the line with the copy operation down to the bottom, otherwise the configuration is not copied, because it is not there yet.

The exception happens, because there is no rendering definition for the menu (because you never copied the configuration).

To see the real error instead of the exception, switch to the development preset in the install tool oder add the following line to your TS setup:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but found it's not using the typoscript menu definitions (even the presets), I am assuming it's using some other fluid ones.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this :

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    menu_type.addItems.101 = My Menu
}
```

as far as I know should be this :

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.menu_type {
   types {
      menu{
         addItems {
            101 = My Menu
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I had to 'tweak' the special menus (typo3 7.6) and this worked:
[Add special menu and add class="active" in TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539413/typo3-special-menu-add-class-active)

Comment: Then you use fluidstyledcontent and not cssstyledcontent.

Comment: indeed .... I saw v7.6.x so for the special menus that should be fluid styled ... am I missing something ?

Comment: You can use both ways in 7.6. It depends on what extension is loaded to define the default rendering for `tt_content`. You can also write this all for yourself.